# failurejava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT when getting response from Wordpress REST API to Android

Tags: java, android, wordpress, rest

recently I am trying to call response from Wordpress REST API in my Android application to display Wordpress's posts on the app. I follow an tutorial on Youtube, but when I run on my app, I can not get response from Wordpress which means no post is displayed and the progress bar keeps rolling. Can anyone help me fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

UIActivity.java

```
private String baseURL = "http://vyarchanics.co.nf/";
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ui);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(UIActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        //call retrofit to pass content to list
        getRetrofit();

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list, UIActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void getRetrofit() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
        Call<List<WPPost>> call = service.getPostInfo();



        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
                Log.e("UIActivity", "response" + response.body());

                //Disable progress bar whenever receive the response
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //Loop for all the body content
                for (int i=0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {

                    list.add(new Model(response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(), response.body().get(i).getContent().getRendered()));
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {

            }

        });
    }
```

RetrofitArrayApi

```
public interface RetrofitArrayApi {

    @GET("/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
    Call<List<WPPost>> getPostInfo();
}
```

Model class

```
public class Model {

    public String title, content;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Model(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

WPPost

```
public class WPPost {
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private Title title;
    @SerializedName("content")
    @Expose
    private Content content;
    public Title getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(Title title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Content getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Content content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Note: The failure message said: "UIActivity: failurejava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2060 path $[0]._links.collection[0]"

Comment: Show us the error message from `onFailure`

Comment: It did not show any error message. Just no post is shown up on the app interface

Comment: Write this in `onFailure` `Log.e("UIActivity", "failure" + t.getMessage());`

Comment: it said "UIActivity: failurejava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2060 path $[0]._links.collection[0]"

Comment: The problem as EliasMohammdi said you have to create another object and add an arraylist of `WPPost` and make the `RetrofitArrayApi` return  `Call<newObject>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `baseUrl` ends with `/` 
And your endpoints start with `/`... delete `/` from the start of  your endpoints like this

`@GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts")`

**Edit:** I think the problem is in your `WPPost`
You use Gson to convert JSON to your model..but your model property isn't like your JSON response.so Gson can not map property. please check it.

for example, I call you're API and get JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 28,
    "date": "2019-07-19T17:34:57",
    "date_gmt": "2019-07-19T17:34:57",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://vyarchanics.co.nf/2019/07/19/post/"
    },
    "modified": "2019-07-19T23:46:26",
    "modified_gmt": "2019-07-19T23:46:26",
    "slug": "post",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "http://vyarchanics.co.nf/2019/07/19/post/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Sample Post"
    },...
```

but in your model, I can't see property `link` or `type` or etc.
You can google this "**JSON to POJO**" and convert, you're JSON response to POJO class. Copy Result and enjoy POJO class.

Comment: I have all these methods, however, I just make the code short so that it is easier to get the idea. The error is: "UIActivity: failurejava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2060 path $[0]._links.collection[0]"